# Changes made in .js not being reflecting when I debug in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to debug problems in a javascript file.  When I make a change to the file and start the Visual Studio Debugger (F5) a [dynamic] version of the javascript file shows up in the debugger and stops at my break point, but the change I made to the file is not reflected in the [dynamic] version.  For example, here is the function in the javascript file:

```
function GetJobNotes(ScheduleID) {
    var par = "ScheduleID='" + ScheduleID + "'";
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "MaskingScheduleService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        //data: par,
        dataType: "xml",
        //success: GetInfoSuccess,
        //error: ProcessError
    });
    alert("ajax called");
}
```

and here is what shows up in the [dynamic] version of the file when debugging:

```
function GetJobNotes(ScheduleID) {
    var par = "ScheduleID='" + ScheduleID + "'";
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "services/MaskingSchedule.asmx/GetJobNotes",
        data: par,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: GetInfoSuccess,
        error: ProcessError
    });
}
```

How do I get the [dynamic] version to match the code in my javascript file?

Comment: Try to delete `bin` and `obj` folder, clean chrome caches, also, when you reference the js file, try to add '?' like `<script src="script.js?0001"><script>`.

Comment: Also, try to use control+F5 to refresh your browser.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I was able to find a setting in Chrome (which I am using for my browser) to block the cache, which allowed the program to always use the current version of the .js file.

Comment: Also, you can add a comment under the answer to share the detailed configuration with the workaround and this will lead a better guidance.

Comment: Please let us know any progress.

Comment: In Chrome, when you start Visual Studio debugging process, press F12, select the Network menu option at the top of the screen, and there is an option - Disable Cache.  Check that and then refresh your web page and it will load the latest version of the javascript file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that there is an option in Chrome that breaks the updated js file. With that option, Chrome will block the changed js content and always use the previous js content.

**Solution**

When starting vs debugging under Chrome, please press **F12** and then select **Network** menu.

This is an option called **Disable cache**

[image]

**Check** this option and then **refresh** your web page and it will load the latest version of the javascript file.